# No signature of method error while using Groovy in Bonita

Tags: groovy, bonita

I'm using Bonita 7.7.4. Groovy script can be used in Bonita.
I wrote below script and it worked, But when 'status' field doesn't exits, it has error.

```
String status = apiAccessor.identityAPI.getCustomUserInfo(startedById, 0, 1000).stream().filter({ row ->
        "status" == row.getDefinition().getName() 
}).findFirst().orElse("").getValue();
```

errors:

```
Possible solutions: getClass(), getAt(int), getAt(groovy.lang.Range), getAt(java.lang.String), getAt(groovy.lang.Range), getAt(java.util.Collection) ( ). ( )
at org.bonitasoft.engine.execution.ProcessExecutorImpl.start(ProcessExecutorImpl.java:839)
at org.bonitasoft.engine.execution.ProcessExecutorImpl.start(ProcessExecutorImpl.java:782)
at org.bonitasoft.engine.api.impl.ProcessStarter.start(ProcessStarter.java:132)
at org.bonitasoft.engine.api.impl.ProcessStarter.start(ProcessStarter.java:103)
at ... 44 more. ( )
at  Caused by: org.bonitasoft.engine.expression.exception.SExpressionEvaluationException.: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.getValue() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
 Possible solutions: getClass(), getAt(int), getAt(groovy.lang.Range), getAt(java.lang.String), getAt(groovy.lang.Range), getAt(java.util.Collection) ( ). ( )
at org.bonitasoft.engine.expression.impl.GroovyScriptExpressionExecutorCacheStrategy.evaluate(GroovyScriptExpressionExecutorCacheStrategy.java:147)
at org.bonitasoft.engine.expression.impl.ExpressionServiceImpl.evaluate(ExpressionServiceImpl.java:86)
at org.bonitasoft.engine.core.expression.control.api.impl.ExpressionResolverServiceImpl.evaluateExpressionWithResolvedDependencies(ExpressionResolverServiceImpl.java:213)
at org.bonitasoft.engine.core.expression.control.api.impl.ExpressionResolverServiceImpl.evaluateExpressionsFlatten(ExpressionResolverServiceImpl.java:120)
at org.bonitasoft.engine.core.expression.control.api.impl.ExpressionResolverServiceImpl.evaluate(ExpressionResolverServiceImpl.java:83)
at org.bonitasoft.engine.execution.ProcessExecutorImpl.initializeSingleBusinessData(ProcessExecutorImpl.java:448)
at org.bonitasoft.engine.execution.ProcessExecutorImpl.initializeBusinessData(ProcessExecutorImpl.java:435)
at org.bonitasoft.engine.execution.ProcessExecutorImpl.initialize(ProcessExecutorImpl.java:387)
at org.bonitasoft.engine.execution.ProcessExecutorImpl.start(ProcessExecutorImpl.java:824)
at ... 47 more. ( )
at  Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException.: No signature of method: java.lang.String.getValue() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
  Possible solutions: getClass(), getAt(int), getAt(groovy.lang.Range),   getAt(java.lang.String), getAt(groovy.lang.Range), getAt(java.util.Collection) ( ). ( )
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:49)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
at BScript83.run(BScript83.groovy:47)
at org.bonitasoft.engine.expression.impl.GroovyScriptExpressionExecutorCacheStrategy.evaluate(GroovyScriptExpressionExecutorCacheStrategy.java:141)
at ... 55 more. ( )
```

Comment: `No signature of method: java.lang.String.getValue()` at `....orElse("").getValue()` seems to be the most likely place it happens.

Comment: Because you have `.orElse("")` that returns string. And string does not have getValue() method

Comment: yeah, you'r right, I changed it and it works: .orElse(null)?.getValue();

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
.findFirst().orElse("").getValue();
```

Use this instead

```
.findFirst().orElse("");
```

### Explanation

`findFirst()` is called on a `Stream<String>`, so it returns an `Optional<String>`. If the stream is empty `.orElse("")` ensures that an empty string will be returned instead of the first element of the stream. Obviously, if you would rather return `null` instead when the stream is empty, use the following

```
.findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are writing Java 8 code, you may opt for the Groovy syntax:

```
def status = apiAccessor.identityAPI
                 .getCustomUserInfo(startedById, 0, 1000)
                 .find { "status" == it.getDefinition().getName() }
                 ?.getValue()
```